# pull out metrics from spark logs

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

[image]how do I pull out these metrics from spark history logs? Is there some api I can pull these from?

I tried downloading the json event logs, but I can't grep for the numbers seen in the photo

Answer (score 0):

The [spark history server](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact) keeps all that information for you.  You can access it via a rest API.

If you are on [EMR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-webui.html):

> You can view the Spark web UIs by following the procedures to create
> an SSH tunnel or create a proxy in the section called Connect to the
> cluster in the Amazon EMR Management Guide and then navigating to the
> YARN ResourceManager for your cluster. Choose the link under Tracking
> UI for your application. If your application is running, you see
> ApplicationMaster. This takes you to the application master's web UI
> at port 20888 wherever the driver is located. The driver may be
> located on the cluster's primary node if you run in YARN client mode.
> If you are running an application in YARN cluster mode, the driver is
> located in the ApplicationMaster for the application on the cluster.
> If your application has finished, you see History, which takes you to
> the Spark HistoryServer UI port number at 18080 of the EMR cluster's
> primary node. This is for applications that have already completed.
> You can also navigate to the Spark HistoryServer UI directly at
> http://master-public-dns-name:18080/.

Comment: how would I grab that in aws emr?